# Finding the projection of a vector into a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F = \mathbb{R}$ and $V$ be a vector space over $F$. Suppose $U$ is the subspace of $V$ spanned by $
    \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           -1
         \end{bmatrix}
  $ and $
    \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
           -1
         \end{bmatrix}
  $. Furthermore, $U$ has orthonormal basis $\{u_1, u_2\}$.

Find $\sum_{i=1}^2 \langle u_i, v \rangle u_i $ for any $v \in V$.

Comment: What do you know and what have you tried? Are your two column vectors supposed to be $u_1$ and $u_2$, respectively? What is $v$?

Comment: Do you know the Graham-Schmidt process to find the ortho-normal basis?

Comment: The Graham-Schmidt process converts a basis to an ortho-normal basis.

Comment: oh. so i use Grahm-schmidt to find the orthonormal basis based from a known basis which is the given spanning set? my question is i am not sure if the orthonormal basis unique. furthermore, is the projection unique?

Comment: Doug i think your last comment is missing something

Comment: Whatever basis you find, won't be unique.  But, that is okay.

Comment: But is the projection unique?

Comment: $\sum <u_i, v> u_i = v$ when $v \in U$ and yes, when $v$ is not in $U$ the projection is unique.

Comment: Why would $\sum \langle u_i, v \rangle u_i= v$ if $v \in U$?

Comment: if $v\in U \implies v = m u_1 + n u_2$ since $(u_1,u_2)$ is an ortho-normal basis $<u_1, m u_1 + n u_2> u_1 = m u_1$ and $<u_2, m u_1 + n u_2> u_2 = n u_1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49271/discussion-between-lanturn-and-doug-m).

Comment: " $u_1,u_2$ is a basis but is not orthonormal" your question currently explicitly says otherwise.

Comment: Oops sorry. I was talking about the given spanning set.

Answer (score 1):

$v_1,v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Graham Schmid process.

find  $v_2 - \frac {<v_1,v_2>}{\|v_1\|^2}v_1$

$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac {1}{2}\\1\\-\frac {1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Divide $v_1$ and this vector you have just found, each by its respective norm.

That is your basis $u_1, u_2$

$\sum <u_1, v> u_1 = v$ if $v\in U$
and is the projection onto $U$ if $v$ is not in $U$